# Unable to load Spring Framework Libraries in Wildfly accessible to deployed JAR

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, keycloak

I am writing a custom Keycloak User Storage SPI, which is JAR file. I would like to use Spring DI in the JAR. I have added Spring JARs as Modules in Keycloak's Wildfly server.

Also, not able to load Spring context as Keycloak User Storage SPI initiate from META-INF.services "org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory" and invokes UserStorageProviderFactory.init method.

It also doesn't read the properties file inside resources directory.

Please advise how can I make this work.

Comment: So what is the error message(s) your are seeing?

Comment: apologies for delay in responding. when custom user storage SPI loads during keycloak server start, it doesn't read the properties file inside resources directory. I'm injecting few properties but accessing using @Value annotation but they are null.

Comment: @user3058277 were you able to use Spring DI in Keycloak User Storage SPI ? trying to do the same if you could please share it would be of great help

Answer (score 0):

May be, there would be workaround by using .ear file with your jar wrapped into it. If you are using maven then you can reside all required spring dependencies in that pom of your jar.
For further reference, you can go to this git link which might be related to what you are doing.

https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-user-storage-provider-demo